# Portable regex equivalent of C# \p{_xmlI}[\p{_xmlC}-[:]]*

Tags: regex

I found a regex in some C# code that seems to work only on Windows:

```
\p{_xmlI}[\p{_xmlC}-[:]]*
```

Does anyone know an equivalent of this regex that works on other platforms, too?

I didn't find much information on the `_xmlI` an `_xmlC` Unicode categories on Google.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please describe your problem, and provide sample input and expected output for us to help you solve the issue. Right now, all I can tell you it is not a valid .NET regex since `_xmlI` and `_xmlC` [Unicode character classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) are not documented and supported.

Comment: The closest to the regex syntax I know from this is that ${...} its used in .Net and Java to replace named Capture Groups

Comment: @stribizhev - Surprisingly, it does seem to work: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cp%7b_xmlI%7d%2b&i=Does+it+work%3f

Comment: I tested in Expresso, it warned of a possibly non-existing category used in the regex. So, it is possible these categories were added recently.

Comment: Hello, thanks you everyone. To give more information @stribizhev, the regex is part of a Codeplex project named XpathParser, that aims, as you can imagine, to parse Xpath expression. Here is the link to the project and its sources : [link](http://xpathparser.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 3):

You can see the .Net source code to see what `\p{_xmlI}` and `\p{_xmlC}` match: 
[RegexCharClass.cs,208](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexCharClass.cs,208).

```
{"_xmlC", /* Name Char              */   "\u002D\u002F\u0030\u003B\u0041\u005B\u005F\u0060\u0061\u007B\u00B7\u00B8\u00C0\u00D7\u00D8\u00F7\u00F8\u0132\u0134\u013F\u0141\u0149\u014A\u017F\u0180\u01C4\u01CD\u01F1\u01F4\u01F6\u01FA\u0218\u0250\u02A9\u02BB\u02C2\u02D0\u02D2\u0300\u0346\u0360\u0362\u0386\u038B\u038C\u038D\u038E\u03A2\u03A3\u03CF\u03D0\u03D7\u03DA\u03DB\u03DC\u03DD\u03DE\u03DF\u03E0\u03E1\u03E2\u03F4\u0401\u040D\u040E\u0450\u0451\u045D\u045E\u0482\u0483\u0487\u0490\u04C5\u04C7\u04C9\u04CB\u04CD\u04D0\u04EC\u04EE\u04F6\u04F8\u04FA\u0531\u0557\u0559\u055A\u0561\u0587\u0591\u05A2\u05A3\u05BA\u05BB\u05BE\u05BF\u05C0\u05C1\u05C3\u05C4\u05C5\u05D0\u05EB\u05F0\u05F3\u0621\u063B\u0640\u0653\u0660\u066A\u0670\u06B8\u06BA\u06BF\u06C0\u06CF\u06D0\u06D4\u06D5\u06E9\u06EA\u06EE\u06F0\u06FA\u0901\u0904\u0905\u093A\u093C\u094E\u0951\u0955\u0958\u0964\u0966\u0970\u0981\u0984\u0985\u098D\u098F\u0991\u0993\u09A9\u09AA\u09B1\u09B2\u09B3\u09B6\u09BA\u09BC\u09BD\u09BE\u09C5\u09C7\u09C9\u09CB\u09CE\u09D7\u09D8\u09DC"
    +"\u09DE\u09DF\u09E4\u09E6\u09F2\u0A02\u0A03\u0A05\u0A0B\u0A0F\u0A11\u0A13\u0A29\u0A2A\u0A31\u0A32\u0A34\u0A35\u0A37\u0A38\u0A3A\u0A3C\u0A3D\u0A3E\u0A43\u0A47\u0A49\u0A4B\u0A4E\u0A59\u0A5D\u0A5E\u0A5F\u0A66\u0A75\u0A81\u0A84\u0A85\u0A8C\u0A8D\u0A8E\u0A8F\u0A92\u0A93\u0AA9\u0AAA\u0AB1\u0AB2\u0AB4\u0AB5\u0ABA\u0ABC\u0AC6\u0AC7\u0ACA\u0ACB\u0ACE\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0AE6\u0AF0\u0B01\u0B04\u0B05\u0B0D\u0B0F\u0B11\u0B13\u0B29\u0B2A\u0B31\u0B32\u0B34\u0B36\u0B3A\u0B3C\u0B44\u0B47\u0B49\u0B4B\u0B4E\u0B56\u0B58\u0B5C\u0B5E\u0B5F\u0B62\u0B66\u0B70\u0B82\u0B84\u0B85\u0B8B\u0B8E\u0B91\u0B92\u0B96\u0B99\u0B9B\u0B9C\u0B9D\u0B9E\u0BA0\u0BA3\u0BA5\u0BA8\u0BAB\u0BAE\u0BB6\u0BB7\u0BBA\u0BBE\u0BC3\u0BC6\u0BC9\u0BCA\u0BCE\u0BD7\u0BD8\u0BE7\u0BF0\u0C01\u0C04\u0C05\u0C0D\u0C0E\u0C11\u0C12\u0C29\u0C2A\u0C34\u0C35\u0C3A\u0C3E\u0C45\u0C46\u0C49\u0C4A\u0C4E\u0C55\u0C57\u0C60\u0C62\u0C66\u0C70\u0C82\u0C84\u0C85\u0C8D\u0C8E\u0C91\u0C92\u0CA9\u0CAA\u0CB4\u0CB5\u0CBA\u0CBE\u0CC5\u0CC6\u0CC9\u0CCA\u0CCE\u0CD5\u0CD7\u0CDE\u0CDF\u0CE0\u0CE2"
    +"\u0CE6\u0CF0\u0D02\u0D04\u0D05\u0D0D\u0D0E\u0D11\u0D12\u0D29\u0D2A\u0D3A\u0D3E\u0D44\u0D46\u0D49\u0D4A\u0D4E\u0D57\u0D58\u0D60\u0D62\u0D66\u0D70\u0E01\u0E2F\u0E30\u0E3B\u0E40\u0E4F\u0E50\u0E5A\u0E81\u0E83\u0E84\u0E85\u0E87\u0E89\u0E8A\u0E8B\u0E8D\u0E8E\u0E94\u0E98\u0E99\u0EA0\u0EA1\u0EA4\u0EA5\u0EA6\u0EA7\u0EA8\u0EAA\u0EAC\u0EAD\u0EAF\u0EB0\u0EBA\u0EBB\u0EBE\u0EC0\u0EC5\u0EC6\u0EC7\u0EC8\u0ECE\u0ED0\u0EDA\u0F18\u0F1A\u0F20\u0F2A\u0F35\u0F36\u0F37\u0F38\u0F39\u0F3A\u0F3E\u0F48\u0F49\u0F6A\u0F71\u0F85\u0F86\u0F8C\u0F90\u0F96\u0F97\u0F98\u0F99\u0FAE\u0FB1\u0FB8\u0FB9\u0FBA\u10A0\u10C6\u10D0\u10F7\u1100\u1101\u1102\u1104\u1105\u1108\u1109\u110A\u110B\u110D\u110E\u1113\u113C\u113D\u113E\u113F\u1140\u1141\u114C\u114D\u114E\u114F\u1150\u1151\u1154\u1156\u1159\u115A\u115F\u1162\u1163\u1164\u1165\u1166\u1167\u1168\u1169\u116A\u116D\u116F\u1172\u1174\u1175\u1176\u119E\u119F\u11A8\u11A9\u11AB\u11AC\u11AE\u11B0\u11B7\u11B9\u11BA\u11BB\u11BC\u11C3\u11EB\u11EC\u11F0\u11F1\u11F9\u11FA\u1E00\u1E9C\u1EA0\u1EFA\u1F00"
    +"\u1F16\u1F18\u1F1E\u1F20\u1F46\u1F48\u1F4E\u1F50\u1F58\u1F59\u1F5A\u1F5B\u1F5C\u1F5D\u1F5E\u1F5F\u1F7E\u1F80\u1FB5\u1FB6\u1FBD\u1FBE\u1FBF\u1FC2\u1FC5\u1FC6\u1FCD\u1FD0\u1FD4\u1FD6\u1FDC\u1FE0\u1FED\u1FF2\u1FF5\u1FF6\u1FFD\u20D0\u20DD\u20E1\u20E2\u2126\u2127\u212A\u212C\u212E\u212F\u2180\u2183\u3005\u3006\u3007\u3008\u3021\u3030\u3031\u3036\u3041\u3095\u3099\u309B\u309D\u309F\u30A1\u30FB\u30FC\u30FF\u3105\u312D\u4E00\u9FA6\uAC00\uD7A4"},
{"_xmlD",                                "\u0030\u003A\u0660\u066A\u06F0\u06FA\u0966\u0970\u09E6\u09F0\u0A66\u0A70\u0AE6\u0AF0\u0B66\u0B70\u0BE7\u0BF0\u0C66\u0C70\u0CE6\u0CF0\u0D66\u0D70\u0E50\u0E5A\u0ED0\u0EDA\u0F20\u0F2A\u1040\u104A\u1369\u1372\u17E0\u17EA\u1810\u181A\uFF10\uFF1A"},
{"_xmlI", /* Start Name Char       */    "\u003A\u003B\u0041\u005B\u005F\u0060\u0061\u007B\u00C0\u00D7\u00D8\u00F7\u00F8\u0132\u0134\u013F\u0141\u0149\u014A\u017F\u0180\u01C4\u01CD\u01F1\u01F4\u01F6\u01FA\u0218\u0250\u02A9\u02BB\u02C2\u0386\u0387\u0388\u038B\u038C\u038D\u038E\u03A2\u03A3\u03CF\u03D0\u03D7\u03DA\u03DB\u03DC\u03DD\u03DE\u03DF\u03E0\u03E1\u03E2\u03F4\u0401\u040D\u040E\u0450\u0451\u045D\u045E\u0482\u0490\u04C5\u04C7\u04C9\u04CB\u04CD\u04D0\u04EC\u04EE\u04F6\u04F8\u04FA\u0531\u0557\u0559\u055A\u0561\u0587\u05D0\u05EB\u05F0\u05F3\u0621\u063B\u0641\u064B\u0671\u06B8\u06BA\u06BF\u06C0\u06CF\u06D0\u06D4\u06D5\u06D6\u06E5\u06E7\u0905\u093A\u093D\u093E\u0958\u0962\u0985\u098D\u098F\u0991\u0993\u09A9\u09AA\u09B1\u09B2\u09B3\u09B6\u09BA\u09DC\u09DE\u09DF\u09E2\u09F0\u09F2\u0A05\u0A0B\u0A0F\u0A11\u0A13\u0A29\u0A2A\u0A31\u0A32\u0A34\u0A35\u0A37\u0A38\u0A3A\u0A59\u0A5D\u0A5E\u0A5F\u0A72\u0A75\u0A85\u0A8C\u0A8D\u0A8E\u0A8F\u0A92\u0A93\u0AA9\u0AAA\u0AB1\u0AB2\u0AB4\u0AB5\u0ABA\u0ABD\u0ABE\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0B05\u0B0D\u0B0F"
    +"\u0B11\u0B13\u0B29\u0B2A\u0B31\u0B32\u0B34\u0B36\u0B3A\u0B3D\u0B3E\u0B5C\u0B5E\u0B5F\u0B62\u0B85\u0B8B\u0B8E\u0B91\u0B92\u0B96\u0B99\u0B9B\u0B9C\u0B9D\u0B9E\u0BA0\u0BA3\u0BA5\u0BA8\u0BAB\u0BAE\u0BB6\u0BB7\u0BBA\u0C05\u0C0D\u0C0E\u0C11\u0C12\u0C29\u0C2A\u0C34\u0C35\u0C3A\u0C60\u0C62\u0C85\u0C8D\u0C8E\u0C91\u0C92\u0CA9\u0CAA\u0CB4\u0CB5\u0CBA\u0CDE\u0CDF\u0CE0\u0CE2\u0D05\u0D0D\u0D0E\u0D11\u0D12\u0D29\u0D2A\u0D3A\u0D60\u0D62\u0E01\u0E2F\u0E30\u0E31\u0E32\u0E34\u0E40\u0E46\u0E81\u0E83\u0E84\u0E85\u0E87\u0E89\u0E8A\u0E8B\u0E8D\u0E8E\u0E94\u0E98\u0E99\u0EA0\u0EA1\u0EA4\u0EA5\u0EA6\u0EA7\u0EA8\u0EAA\u0EAC\u0EAD\u0EAF\u0EB0\u0EB1\u0EB2\u0EB4\u0EBD\u0EBE\u0EC0\u0EC5\u0F40\u0F48\u0F49\u0F6A\u10A0\u10C6\u10D0\u10F7\u1100\u1101\u1102\u1104\u1105\u1108\u1109\u110A\u110B\u110D\u110E\u1113\u113C\u113D\u113E\u113F\u1140\u1141\u114C\u114D\u114E\u114F\u1150\u1151\u1154\u1156\u1159\u115A\u115F\u1162\u1163\u1164\u1165\u1166\u1167\u1168\u1169\u116A\u116D\u116F\u1172\u1174\u1175\u1176\u119E\u119F\u11A8\u11A9\u11AB\u11AC"
    +"\u11AE\u11B0\u11B7\u11B9\u11BA\u11BB\u11BC\u11C3\u11EB\u11EC\u11F0\u11F1\u11F9\u11FA\u1E00\u1E9C\u1EA0\u1EFA\u1F00\u1F16\u1F18\u1F1E\u1F20\u1F46\u1F48\u1F4E\u1F50\u1F58\u1F59\u1F5A\u1F5B\u1F5C\u1F5D\u1F5E\u1F5F\u1F7E\u1F80\u1FB5\u1FB6\u1FBD\u1FBE\u1FBF\u1FC2\u1FC5\u1FC6\u1FCD\u1FD0\u1FD4\u1FD6\u1FDC\u1FE0\u1FED\u1FF2\u1FF5\u1FF6\u1FFD\u2126\u2127\u212A\u212C\u212E\u212F\u2180\u2183\u3007\u3008\u3021\u302A\u3041\u3095\u30A1\u30FB\u3105\u312D\u4E00\u9FA6\uAC00\uD7A4"},
{"_xmlW",                                "\u0024\u0025\u002B\u002C\u0030\u003A\u003C\u003F\u0041\u005B\u005E\u005F\u0060\u007B\u007C\u007D\u007E\u007F\u00A2\u00AB\u00AC\u00AD\u00AE\u00B7\u00B8\u00BB\u00BC\u00BF\u00C0\u0221\u0222\u0234\u0250\u02AE\u02B0\u02EF\u0300\u0350\u0360\u0370\u0374\u0376\u037A\u037B\u0384\u0387\u0388\u038B\u038C\u038D\u038E\u03A2\u03A3\u03CF\u03D0\u03F7\u0400\u0487\u0488\u04CF\u04D0\u04F6\u04F8\u04FA\u0500\u0510\u0531\u0557\u0559\u055A\u0561\u0588\u0591\u05A2\u05A3\u05BA\u05BB\u05BE\u05BF\u05C0\u05C1\u05C3\u05C4\u05C5\u05D0\u05EB\u05F0\u05F3\u0621\u063B\u0640\u0656\u0660\u066A\u066E\u06D4\u06D5\u06DD\u06DE\u06EE\u06F0\u06FF\u0710\u072D\u0730\u074B\u0780\u07B2\u0901\u0904\u0905\u093A\u093C\u094E\u0950\u0955\u0958\u0964\u0966\u0970\u0981\u0984\u0985\u098D\u098F\u0991\u0993\u09A9\u09AA\u09B1\u09B2\u09B3\u09B6\u09BA\u09BC\u09BD\u09BE\u09C5\u09C7\u09C9\u09CB\u09CE\u09D7\u09D8\u09DC\u09DE\u09DF\u09E4\u09E6\u09FB\u0A02\u0A03\u0A05\u0A0B\u0A0F\u0A11\u0A13\u0A29\u0A2A\u0A31\u0A32\u0A34\u0A35"
    +"\u0A37\u0A38\u0A3A\u0A3C\u0A3D\u0A3E\u0A43\u0A47\u0A49\u0A4B\u0A4E\u0A59\u0A5D\u0A5E\u0A5F\u0A66\u0A75\u0A81\u0A84\u0A85\u0A8C\u0A8D\u0A8E\u0A8F\u0A92\u0A93\u0AA9\u0AAA\u0AB1\u0AB2\u0AB4\u0AB5\u0ABA\u0ABC\u0AC6\u0AC7\u0ACA\u0ACB\u0ACE\u0AD0\u0AD1\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0AE6\u0AF0\u0B01\u0B04\u0B05\u0B0D\u0B0F\u0B11\u0B13\u0B29\u0B2A\u0B31\u0B32\u0B34\u0B36\u0B3A\u0B3C\u0B44\u0B47\u0B49\u0B4B\u0B4E\u0B56\u0B58\u0B5C\u0B5E\u0B5F\u0B62\u0B66\u0B71\u0B82\u0B84\u0B85\u0B8B\u0B8E\u0B91\u0B92\u0B96\u0B99\u0B9B\u0B9C\u0B9D\u0B9E\u0BA0\u0BA3\u0BA5\u0BA8\u0BAB\u0BAE\u0BB6\u0BB7\u0BBA\u0BBE\u0BC3\u0BC6\u0BC9\u0BCA\u0BCE\u0BD7\u0BD8\u0BE7\u0BF3\u0C01\u0C04\u0C05\u0C0D\u0C0E\u0C11\u0C12\u0C29\u0C2A\u0C34\u0C35\u0C3A\u0C3E\u0C45\u0C46\u0C49\u0C4A\u0C4E\u0C55\u0C57\u0C60\u0C62\u0C66\u0C70\u0C82\u0C84\u0C85\u0C8D\u0C8E\u0C91\u0C92\u0CA9\u0CAA\u0CB4\u0CB5\u0CBA\u0CBE\u0CC5\u0CC6\u0CC9\u0CCA\u0CCE\u0CD5\u0CD7\u0CDE\u0CDF\u0CE0\u0CE2\u0CE6\u0CF0\u0D02\u0D04\u0D05\u0D0D\u0D0E\u0D11\u0D12\u0D29\u0D2A\u0D3A\u0D3E\u0D44\u0D46\u0D49"
    +"\u0D4A\u0D4E\u0D57\u0D58\u0D60\u0D62\u0D66\u0D70\u0D82\u0D84\u0D85\u0D97\u0D9A\u0DB2\u0DB3\u0DBC\u0DBD\u0DBE\u0DC0\u0DC7\u0DCA\u0DCB\u0DCF\u0DD5\u0DD6\u0DD7\u0DD8\u0DE0\u0DF2\u0DF4\u0E01\u0E3B\u0E3F\u0E4F\u0E50\u0E5A\u0E81\u0E83\u0E84\u0E85\u0E87\u0E89\u0E8A\u0E8B\u0E8D\u0E8E\u0E94\u0E98\u0E99\u0EA0\u0EA1\u0EA4\u0EA5\u0EA6\u0EA7\u0EA8\u0EAA\u0EAC\u0EAD\u0EBA\u0EBB\u0EBE\u0EC0\u0EC5\u0EC6\u0EC7\u0EC8\u0ECE\u0ED0\u0EDA\u0EDC\u0EDE\u0F00\u0F04\u0F13\u0F3A\u0F3E\u0F48\u0F49\u0F6B\u0F71\u0F85\u0F86\u0F8C\u0F90\u0F98\u0F99\u0FBD\u0FBE\u0FCD\u0FCF\u0FD0\u1000\u1022\u1023\u1028\u1029\u102B\u102C\u1033\u1036\u103A\u1040\u104A\u1050\u105A\u10A0\u10C6\u10D0\u10F9\u1100\u115A\u115F\u11A3\u11A8\u11FA\u1200\u1207\u1208\u1247\u1248\u1249\u124A\u124E\u1250\u1257\u1258\u1259\u125A\u125E\u1260\u1287\u1288\u1289\u128A\u128E\u1290\u12AF\u12B0\u12B1\u12B2\u12B6\u12B8\u12BF\u12C0\u12C1\u12C2\u12C6\u12C8\u12CF\u12D0\u12D7\u12D8\u12EF\u12F0\u130F\u1310\u1311\u1312\u1316\u1318\u131F\u1320\u1347\u1348\u135B\u1369\u137D\u13A0"
    +"\u13F5\u1401\u166D\u166F\u1677\u1681\u169B\u16A0\u16EB\u16EE\u16F1\u1700\u170D\u170E\u1715\u1720\u1735\u1740\u1754\u1760\u176D\u176E\u1771\u1772\u1774\u1780\u17D4\u17D7\u17D8\u17DB\u17DD\u17E0\u17EA\u180B\u180E\u1810\u181A\u1820\u1878\u1880\u18AA\u1E00\u1E9C\u1EA0\u1EFA\u1F00\u1F16\u1F18\u1F1E\u1F20\u1F46\u1F48\u1F4E\u1F50\u1F58\u1F59\u1F5A\u1F5B\u1F5C\u1F5D\u1F5E\u1F5F\u1F7E\u1F80\u1FB5\u1FB6\u1FC5\u1FC6\u1FD4\u1FD6\u1FDC\u1FDD\u1FF0\u1FF2\u1FF5\u1FF6\u1FFF\u2044\u2045\u2052\u2053\u2070\u2072\u2074\u207D\u207F\u208D\u20A0\u20B2\u20D0\u20EB\u2100\u213B\u213D\u214C\u2153\u2184\u2190\u2329\u232B\u23B4\u23B7\u23CF\u2400\u2427\u2440\u244B\u2460\u24FF\u2500\u2614\u2616\u2618\u2619\u267E\u2680\u268A\u2701\u2705\u2706\u270A\u270C\u2728\u2729\u274C\u274D\u274E\u274F\u2753\u2756\u2757\u2758\u275F\u2761\u2768\u2776\u2795\u2798\u27B0\u27B1\u27BF\u27D0\u27E6\u27F0\u2983\u2999\u29D8\u29DC\u29FC\u29FE\u2B00\u2E80\u2E9A\u2E9B\u2EF4\u2F00\u2FD6\u2FF0\u2FFC\u3004\u3008\u3012\u3014\u3020\u3030\u3031\u303D\u303E\u3040"
    +"\u3041\u3097\u3099\u30A0\u30A1\u30FB\u30FC\u3100\u3105\u312D\u3131\u318F\u3190\u31B8\u31F0\u321D\u3220\u3244\u3251\u327C\u327F\u32CC\u32D0\u32FF\u3300\u3377\u337B\u33DE\u33E0\u33FF\u3400\u4DB6\u4E00\u9FA6\uA000\uA48D\uA490\uA4C7\uAC00\uD7A4\uF900\uFA2E\uFA30\uFA6B\uFB00\uFB07\uFB13\uFB18\uFB1D\uFB37\uFB38\uFB3D\uFB3E\uFB3F\uFB40\uFB42\uFB43\uFB45\uFB46\uFBB2\uFBD3\uFD3E\uFD50\uFD90\uFD92\uFDC8\uFDF0\uFDFD\uFE00\uFE10\uFE20\uFE24\uFE62\uFE63\uFE64\uFE67\uFE69\uFE6A\uFE70\uFE75\uFE76\uFEFD\uFF04\uFF05\uFF0B\uFF0C\uFF10\uFF1A\uFF1C\uFF1F\uFF21\uFF3B\uFF3E\uFF3F\uFF40\uFF5B\uFF5C\uFF5D\uFF5E\uFF5F\uFF66\uFFBF\uFFC2\uFFC8\uFFCA\uFFD0\uFFD2\uFFD8\uFFDA\uFFDD\uFFE0\uFFE7\uFFE8\uFFEF\uFFFC\uFFFE"},
```

It is not pretty, and as  Stribizhev commented, doesn't seem to be documented.

Note that these are *ranges*, not individual characters, and the ranges do not include the last character.
`\u0041\u005B` is the range`[A-Z]` - [`\u005B`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005B/index.htm) is actually `[`, with `Z` being [`\u005A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005A/index.htm).

I suspect there are easier ways to achieve that in most languages, for example `\p{L}` for all Unicode letters, etc.

Comment: @Mints97 - If I have to *guess* - Visual Studio used to have its own weird Regex syntax, with classes like `:i` (IRRC) for a legal identifier (e.g. variable name). At some point they switched to .Net regex - maybe this was added to support some use cases. This is pretty out there. A more likely option is [regex for XSD validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256072.aspx), but I didn't find it there either.

Comment: That would be my guess, too. The block comment on [line 146f](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexCharClass.cs,146) refers to the XML Schema spec and the comments  indicate "start of name" and "name"; so the regex apparently attempts to capture  valid XML  identifiers. (Not sure what's up with the `-[:]` at the end, though.)

Comment: @tripleee - You probably mean [line 93](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexCharClass.cs,93) - Good point. I didn't think about reading the comments...

Comment: Hmm, your line numbers don't seem to agree with mine at all. I don't see how that could be, but that's how it seems.

Comment: `-[:]` is a character class subtraction. Now, after you found out what those categories mean, i see that the regex matches a character from class `\p{_xmlI}`, then 0 or more characters belonging to class `\p{_xmlC}` excluding `:`.